# Randomly Tests failed with session cannot be created error while running Test cases in selenium grid on docker on linux

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenoid

While executing the Tests on scheduled jenkins job which are running in selenium grid docker , Randomly a bunch of Tests fail giving following error :

Error : cannot create session chrome-91.0-LINUX on any hosts after 1 attempt(s) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10 milliseconds.

Stacktrace : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
cannot create session chrome-91.0-LINUX on any hosts after 1 attempt(s) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10 milliseconds.

what I am doing is creating session before every Test case start and quitting driver after Test ends .
Using chrome 91 version.

Comment: Exact error message is in Selenoid or another Selenium server logs which is behind Ggr.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the slave that runs the tests and run "docker ps". If you see lots of Selenoid containers you don't need - kill them. It helped me with the exact same error.
If it doesn't help, you should make sure you have enough disk space, CPU and memory on your slave.